# Debugging, Stepping through AspectJ woven classes methods

Tags: eclipse, spring, debugging, netbeans, aspectj

I'm using Spring(3.2.2) + AspectJ (1.7.2) Load Time Weaving.
Developing using Netbeans 7.3.

I've noticed that I cannot "step over" while debugging methods in classes that were woven by AspectJ, for example inside methods annotated with @Transactional.

I am able to put break points, but when I "Step over" the debug flow jumps to line 1 of the class and if click "Step over" again, it jumps to other classes.

Tried to run it in IntelliJ 12.1.3, same problem as in Netbeans...

When debugging the same project in Eclipse Juno SR2, the "step over" is going fine, with the exception that for the first line in the method I have to click twice.

Tried to add -XnoInline option to aop.xml, but it didn't help.

I've found a similar question [Eclipse debug stepping with AspectJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762142/eclipse-debug-stepping-with-aspectj) but I find the answer not complete:

1. What is the issue id/link?
2. To which versions does it apply?
3. When will it be fixed?
4. Are there other workarounds?
5. Why is it working in Eclipse, does it have a workaround/feature?

**Update 1**

I didn't mention that the debugging in Intellij IDEA was through remote debugging.
When I debugged directly in the IDE it stepped over fine...

In Eclipse I've tried and it works fine in both normal and remote debugging.

In Netbeans neigher normal/local nor remote debugging steps over fine(line after line) - still an issue.

**Update 2**

I've found out what is the problem in debugging that code.

Spring in version 3.2.2 has changed the @Transactional aspect, replaced @Before and @After combination with @Around.

When running my tests with Spring < 3.2.2, debugging works fine.

It's a pity that @Around makes the @Transactional methods almost impossible to debug.

Is this a know issue(using @Around) in AspectJ?

I've added a spring issue related to this problem: 
https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-10596

**Update 3**

In Netbeans 7.4, it is possible to use "Step over expression (Shift+F8)" instead "Step over (F8)" to step through the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is actually with IntelliJ not supporting their frame rewriting to remove the @Around code frames in the same way they do for @Before/@After.  This issue has been filed with them http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-119214